# Not able to add Company Name in Customer grid during order creation

Tags: magento2

Please check attached screenshot of my code, I am able to show Company Name in Customer Grid but data is not showing. Please check attached screenshots.
File Paths are 
1) Vendor\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_create_customer_block.xml
[image]
2)Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection.php
[image]

OutPut
[image]